# How can I tell if my Cordova application is running on a simulator or real device?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'd like to be talk to a different server when running in an emulator / simulator.

It looks like device.platform used to mention the simulator, but know it just says "iOS". The user-agent doesn't seem to differentiate either.

Ideally the solution would work for all platforms, but I'll take Android and iOS, or in fact anything helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the most recent version of the Device plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-device), there is now a isVirtual property that represents this.

Answer (score 3):

For iOS I just check the model - if matches /x86/ then it's the simulator (until Apple release an Intel iOS device).

```
function isRunningInSimulator(device) {
    // Only valid after deviceReady
    return device && device.model.match(/x86/);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible to detect. One "workaround" is use a task manager (grunt, gulp, whatever) to copy configuration files from on folder to other. Then instead of running "cordova run android" (example) at the command line, you would run a task that copies the config file(s) from one specific folder (i.e.: development or production) an the application read the copied file.

You can take a look here http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/ at the section "Replace Text Depending on Environment"

Comment: I'm already using make to manage the build, so I could do as you suggest - that's a good link thanks.